# как объединить несколько функций если() в эксель

Tags: excel, if

Вот первый столбец который содержит следующие значения:
Результат
Доработка
Подготовлен
На разработке
Изменение

Рядом в другом столбце мне нужно проставить следующие значения:
если "Результат" то **1**
если "Доработка" то **2**
если "Подготовлен" то **3**
если "На разработке" то **4**
если "Изменение" то **5**

Факт в том что в первом столбце могут встречаться и другие значения, например:
СТТ01, Результат
СТТ01, Доработка
СТТ05, Подготовлен

в этом случае, условия те же, если он находит слово **Результат** в первом столбце то он должен проставить **1**.

Как это сделать?

Вот этот пример из двух значений не работает:

```
=ЕСЛИ(ПОИСК("Результат";[@Tags]);1;ЕСЛИ(ПОИСК("Доработка";[@Tags]);2;0))
```

Comment: Вариант 1 `ЕСЛИ( A1="Результат"; 1; ECЛИ(A1="Доработка";2; и так далее))`

Comment: спасибо, но я забыла указать еще критерий, обновила задачу, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: с `ЕОШ` выдает наоборот значение, `=ЕСЛИ(ЕОШ(ПОИСК("Результат";[@Tags])>0);1;0)`  Т.е. где должно быть 1 почему то пишет 0, и наоборот. @Batanichek

Comment: с минусом сработало, но только для одного значения, когда я добавила следующее, оно вообщем не правильно показывать начало. Вот `=ЕСЛИ(-ЕОШ(ПОИСК("Результат";[@Tags])>0);1;ЕСЛИ(-ЕОШ(ПОИСК("Доработка";[@Tags])>0);2;0))`

Comment: Исправила, но все значения 1 или 2, нулей нет, хотя если нет такого слово должно же 0 выйти? `=ЕСЛИ(-ЕОШ(ПОИСК("Результат;[@Tags]));1;ЕСЛИ(-ЕОШ(ПОИСК("Доработка";[@Tags]));2;0))`

Comment: @Batanichek не уходите)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для `поиск` внутри  `если` можно использовать вот такую комбинацию `ЕОШ` и `НЕ`

`=ЕСЛИ(НЕ(ЕОШ(ПОИСК("Результат";A1)));1;ЕСЛИ(НЕ(ЕОШ(ПОИСК("Доработка";A1)));2;0))`

Пример с результатом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вообщем основа такая же, но я сделала 5 отдельных столбцов, потому что боле 1-го значения он показывает не правильно. Например если **Результат** то 1, если нет то 0. Потом просуммировала их в один, и в итоге получила 1 столбец со всеми значениями. Спасибо!

Comment: сделала в точности как у вас, и все заработало :)

Comment: *НЕ(ЕОШ(...* можно заменить на *ЕЧИСЛО* ===О пяти столбцах не понял. Зачем, если можно воспользоваться короткой формулой, показанной в моем сообщении или  в третьем варианте от *nick_n_a*

Answer (score 3):

В Excel 2016, Excel Online, Excel for Android tablets, Excel Mobile, Excel for Android phones есть функция `SWITCH`. Формат использования такой

```
= SWITCH(<что сравниваем>, 
  <значение1>, , <возвращаемое значение1>,
  <значение2>, , <возвращаемое значение2>,
  ..........
  <значениеN>, , <возвращаемое значениеN>,
  <значение по умолчанию>
)
```

минимальное число входных параметров - 3, максимальное значение проверяемых значений - 126

Для более старых версий можно написать UDF на VBA или использовать каскад `IF()`

```
= IF (<условие1>, <значение 1>,
    IF (<условие2>, <значение 2>,
       ..................
      IF (<условиеN>, <значение N>, <значение по умолчанию>
  )....))
```

Comment: у меня excel 2013

Answer (score 2):

Вариант 1 `=ЕСЛИ( A1="Результат"; 1; ECЛИ(A1="Доработка";2; и так далее))`

Вариант 2.  Создаём таблицу, допустим `H:I`.  В H1 пишем Доработка, в I1 2
в H2 Изменение,  в I2 5. и так далее, таблица должна быть отсортирована по 1-му столбцу (искомому, т.е. можно вбить таблицу как есть, а потом отсортировать по Н). Далее пишем `=ВПР(A1;H:I;2)` и excel выбирает из таблицы второй столбец - т.е. соответствие А1 из таблицы.

Учитывая доп условие, могу предложить `=ВПР( СЖПРОБЕЛЫ( ПСТР(A1; НАЙТИ(",";A1)+1;100)) ; I:H;2)` а лучше `=ВПР( СЖПРОБЕЛЫ( ПСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A1;" ";ПОВТОР(" ";99));ДЛСТР(A1);199));H:I;2)` - разделение по последнему слову (взято из http://www.planetaexcel.ru/forum/?PAGE_NAME=read&FID=8&TID=44801) проверив `СЖПРОБЕЛЫ( ПСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A1;" ";ПОВТОР(" ";99));ДЛСТР(A1);199))` возможно 199 прийдется увеличить.

Вариант 3. Массив можно обьявить через ":" тогда можно вообще так:
`=ПОИСКПОЗ(A1;{"Результат":"Доработка":"Подготовлен":"В разработке":"Изменение"};0)` т.е. при одном разделителе запятая можно так `=ПОИСКПОЗ(СЖПРОБЕЛЫ( ПСТР(A1; НАЙТИ(",";A1)+1;100));{"Результат":"Доработка":"Подготовлен":"В разработке":"Изменение"};0)` или при поиске последнего слова через пробел так: `=ПОИСКПОЗ(СЖПРОБЕЛЫ( ПСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A1;" ";ПОВТОР(" ";99));ДЛСТР(A1);199));
{"Результат":"Доработка":"Подготовлен":"разработке":"Изменение"};0)`

Comment: а это сработает если в исходной таблице будет содержаться не только слово **Результат**, а допустим будет **СТТ01, Результат**?

Comment: можете написать пример использую мои значения пожалуйста? А то не совсем понятно что куда относится((

Comment: используя* мои значения

Comment: Да, можно. В дополнении первое - если разделитель запятая будет один и всегда, а ниже - если надо проверить последнее слово.

Comment: В вариантах 2 и 3 можно проще (не думаю, что последнее слово будет больше чем из 99 букв): **=СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(ПРАВСИМВ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A2;" ";ПОВТОР(" ";99));99))**

Answer (score 2):

Не обязательно искать целое слово, можно ограничиться началом или окончанием (при условии, что фрагменты уникальны).

```
=МИН(ЕСЛИ(ПСТР(A2;8;3)={"Рез";"Дор";"Под";"На ";"Изм"};{1;2;3;4;5}))
```

Если текст перед искомым не всегда одинаков, можно искать разделитель - запятую:

```
=МИН(ЕСЛИ(ПСТР(A2;ПОИСК(",";A2)+2;3)={"Рез";"Дор";"Под";"На ";"Изм"};{1;2;3;4;5}))
```

Если ориентироваться на последнее слово, то текст перед этим словом не имеет значения - заменить в формуле *ПСТР* на поиск текста справа:

```
=МИН(ЕСЛИ(ПРАВБ(A2;3)={"тат";"тка";"лен";"тке";"ние"};{1;2;3;4;5}))
```

При отсутствии искомых результат - ноль.

```
-------------------------------------------
```

Варианты  *UDF*

```
' присвоение номера найденному в тексте слову   
Function fStatus(r1 As Range) As Long
    Dim ArrWord()
    Dim s, j As Long
        ' готовим упорядоченный список слов
        ArrWord = Array("Результат", "Доработка", "Подготовлен", "На разработке", "Изменение")

        For Each s In ArrWord
            j = j + 1 ' счетчик значений
            If r1.Value Like "*" & s & "*" Then _
                    fStatus = j: Exit Function ' если слово в тексте найдено, выходим
        Next s
    End Function

' присвоение номера второму слову текста
Function fStatus(r1 As Range) As Long
    Select Case Split(r1.Value, " ")(1)
    Case "Результат": fStatus = 1
    Case "Доработка": fStatus = 2
    Case "Подготовлен": fStatus = 3
    Case "На разработке": fStatus = 4
    Case "Изменение": fStatus = 5
    End Select
End Function
```

Функцию разместить в редакторе *VBA* (войти - *Alt+F11*) в общем модуле.

В ячейку *B2* вписать формулу (принимаем, что тексты в *А2* и ниже):

```
=fStatus(B2)
```

Размножить на нужный диапазон

Недостаток функций пользователя - волатитьность (пересчитываются при любых изменениях на листе)

Answer (score 1):

`=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ЕСЛИ(ПОИСК("Результат";A1)>0;1;-1);ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ЕСЛИ(ПОИСК("Доработка";A1)>0;2;-1);ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ЕСЛИ(ПОИСК("Подготовлен";A1)>0;3;-1);ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ЕСЛИ(ПОИСК("На разработке";A1)>0;4;-1);ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ЕСЛИ(ПОИСК("Изменение";A1)>0;5;-1);-1)))))`